# nreco html to pdf size error

Tags: c#, html, pdf

using the code below. i am able to generate html to pdf. but my problem is i have extra space below.

please see the picture

[image]

but why do i have extra white space. if im setting the custom size of the pdf? or am i doing it wrong?

```
var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
                //htmlToPdf.Size = NReco.PdfGenerator.PageSize.A4;
                htmlToPdf.Margins = new NReco.PdfGenerator.PageMargins { Left = 0, Top = 0, Right = 0, Bottom = 0 };
                    htmlToPdf.Orientation = NReco.PdfGenerator.PageOrientation.Portrait;
                    htmlToPdf.PageWidth = 210f;
                    htmlToPdf.PageHeight = 297f;
                htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFiles(listSortpage.ToArray<string>(), null, savefile.FileName);
```